# Character Count - Show more link

Tags: jquery

I am following this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1156/) link to dynamically add read more to text if it exceeds x no of characters. Working fine with below case.

```
<div class="comment more">weekly, monthly or quarterly analysi...</div>
```

not with this case

```
<div class="comment more"><p>weekly, monthly or quarterly analysi...</p></div>
```

by adding a p tag it stops working

Comment: Provide your html and js code.

Comment: same as the Jsfiddle link, I just added p tag inside <div class="comment more"><p></p></div>

Comment: You need to provide the jquery you're trying to use and be more specific about what you are asking.

Comment: Please provide more context. External links often go bad; and with that possibility it may become impractical to expect sufficiently complete information to be provided otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the `p` element in line `7`+`16` then, to get and set the correct content:

```
var content = $("p", this).html();
// ...
$("p", this).html(html);
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/2940/)**